# replace words from text if match

Tags: java, android, if-statement, for-loop

I want to take what ever word entered and replace it 
with the word "hi"
I am only trying to make it replace on word 
put. When I run it, it crashed.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText r=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String t=r.getText().toString();
    String[] t1= t.split(" ");


    for(int i=0;i<=t1.length;i++)
    {
        if(t[i].equals("hi") )
        {
            TextView uu=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            uu.setText(t[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Post your logcat please.

Comment: "replace it with the word "hi" for know iam only trying to make it replace on word put " doesnt make sense ,make clear so that all can help you

Comment: plz use words correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Just change t[i] to t1[i]

try this

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText r=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String t=r.getText().toString();
    String[] t1= t.split(" ");


    for(int i=0;i<=t1.length;i++)
    {

       if(t1[i].equals("hi") )
      {
         TextView uu=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
         uu.setText(t1[i]);
      }


    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

replace **t1[]** instead of **t[]** inside if block.

try this:

`if(t1[i].equals("hi") )` instead of `if(t[i].equals("hi") )`

Comment: whats the difference in your answer and my answer

Comment: @Drawable, Itś totally different, you have putted about 20 lines of code where I did only the point replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Without the actual error we cannot say much, that being said, this segment:

```
for(int i=0;i<=t1.length;i++)
{    
    if(t[i].equals("hi") )
    {
        TextView uu=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        uu.setText(t[i]);
    }
}
```

Will yield an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` since in Java, arrays are 0 based and the last accessible array location is `[arraySize] - 1`.

Changing it to this:

```
for(int i=0;i<t1.length;i++)
{    
    if(t[i].equals("hi") )
    {
        TextView uu=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        uu.setText(t[i]);
    }
}
```

Should resolve the issue (at least for this particular exception).

That however, should iterate only over the characters making up the phrase, so it should never match `hi`. Changing `t[i]` to `t1[i]` in here: `if(t1[i].equals("hi") )` and possibly here: `uu.setText(t1[i]);` should yield a better solution.

Just as an FYI, using meaningful names never hurts.

Answer (score 0):

why are you initialising everytime

> TextView uu=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

keep this in oncreate() once

Answer (score 0):

```
t[i].equals("hi")
```

Compares objects.
replace it with t1[i].tostring()=="Hi"

Answer (score 0):

I found some mistakes in your code. Don't need split. I think your code should be as

```
final EditText r=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
TextView uu=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
String t=r.getText().toString();
  if(t.contains("hi"))
    {
        // do your stuff
    }
  else{
   //false
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You said that you want to replace whatever word entered with the word "hi". But you are checking if the word (I presume that instead of t[i] you wanted to say t1[i]) is equal to "hi" and then you want to put it in the 2nd textView? You are just going to get the number of "hi"s in your original input. If you want to change ANY word to "hi", just remove the if test and you'll get as many "hi"s as word you have entered.